# Where can I exchange Georgian Lari in Dubai?

Tags: money, exchange, dubai, uae

I have 400 Georgian Lari In UAE (Dubai & sharjah).

Where I could exchange it for AED dihrams or any other currency?

Comment: Have you tried any places?

Comment: In my experience GEL is very difficult to exchange outside Georgia except probably at money changers near the border crossings in Turkey and Armenia. You could probably also change money informally in the Georgian expat communities in Athens and Thessaloniki in Greece.

Comment: Have you tried the old market (Naif street)?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem here is that the Georgian Lari is a [closed currency](http://wikitravel.org/en/Georgia_%28country%29#Costs).  As a result, you aren't meant to legally be able to buy or sell the currency outside of the country, as by law, the currency itself isn't meant to leave the country.

[A representative from the Royal Bank of Scotland](http://forum.virtualtourist.com/Georgia-2854-2-3362012/Is-Georgian-Lari-a-closed-currency.html) confirms this in another forum.